# Laravel 5.3 production gey generate error failed to open stream

Tags: laravel-5

I've copied the example .env file on production server and made a .env with the following info (IP is fake numbers). I get an error when generating the app key saying `PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file` etc.

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=error
APP_URL=http://108.99.999.99

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=108.99.999.99
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=npr
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypasswordhere

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `composer install` or `composer dump-autoload`.

As you don't have `autoload.php` file which is generated by `composer`.

Comment: composer dump-autoload helped. The original error was that my composer install --no-dev didn't run through. There was a php xml file missing. This fixed the rest of the errors.